# Can I rely on the comma operator in a bool expression

Tags: c++, operators

```
void test()
{
    string s = " ,";
    if (boost::trim_if(s, boost::is_any_of(" ,")), s.empty())
    {
        cout << "empty";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

According to this [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work), the expression is supposed to equal to boost::trim_if() which returns void.
But it can work now, so it executes boost::trim_if() and s.empty().
Can I rely on this kind of expression?

You maybe say I should write code like this:

```
boost::trim_if(s, boost::is_any_of(" ,"));
if (s.empty())
{
    cout << "empty";
}
```

But I'm in a condition that our old code is

```
string s;
if(FAILED(GetStringFromAPI(s)) || s.empty() )
{
}
```

I want to just modify one line

```
if(FAILED(GetStringFromAPI(s)) || (boost::trim_if(...), s.empty()) )
{
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, yes I know it checks s.empty(). I want to know if it would definitely execute the left part of the comma.

Comment: It evaluates all it's operands, left to right.

Comment: The question you linked to is about the relative precedences of assignment and the comma and does not say what you think it says. (It says that `x = a, b` means `(x = a), b`, not `x = (a,b)`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is completely fine to use. [cppreference says this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) (empahsis mine):

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression **`E1` is evaluated**, its result is discarded (although if it has class type, it won't be destroyed until the end of the containing full expression), and **its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression `E2` begins**

Note that like other operators, the comma operator can be overridden, in which case the above may not hold true.